# Error with regex, match numbers

Tags: regex, match

I have a string `00000001001300000708303939313833313932E2`

so, I want to match everything between `708 & E2`..

So I wrote:

`(?<=708)(.*\n?)(?=E2)` - tested in RegExr (it's working)

Now, from that result `303939313833313932` match to get result
(every second number):

```
099183192
```

How ?

Comment: Can m/708(.*?)E2/ suit your purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match everything between `708` and `E2`, use:

```
708(\d+)
```

if you are sure that there will be only digits. Otherwise try with:

```
708(.*?)E2
```

To match every second digit from `303939313833313932`, use:

```
(?:\d(\d))+
```

Answer (score 0):

use a global replace:

```
find: \d(\d)
replace: $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting a regular expression answer to this?

You are perhaps better off doing this using string operations in whatever programming language you're using. If you have `text = "abcdefghi..."` then do `output = text[0] + text[2] + text[4]...` in a loop, until you run out of characters.

You haven't specified a programming language, but in Python I would do something like:

```
>>> text = "abcdefghjiklmnop"
>>> for n, char in enumerate(text):
...   if n % 2 == 0: #every second char
...     print char
... 
a
c
e
g
j
k
m
o
```